# how to display grouped values in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in form: date, key, value, n, 
where:

- `date` is the first date and time when a variable key got a specific value.
- `key` is the variable name
- `value` is a value
- `n` is the number of subsequent occurrences of the same value

For example, if `a` has a `value` of 20 from `8am` to `11am` on 2017-01-01, and there are four recordings during that time span, its `n` value for `2017-01-01 8am` would be 4. The reason the data is highly aggregated like this is that there are billions of rows of data.

This is a small example:

```
r1 <- c("2017-01-01 08:00:00","a",20,5) 
r2 <- c("2017-01-01 08:00:00","b",10,20) 
r3 <- c("2017-01-01 14:00:00","a",35,4) 
dat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3) 
colnames(dat) <- c("Date","Key","Value","n")
```

My goal is to show the value distributions over time, using different plots including lines (for time series).

As the amount of data is huge, I'm looking for an effective way of ungrouping this kind of data (i.e. replicating the value n-times) or displaying the data as it is.

Comment: You can repeat the rows n times like so: `dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), times = as.numeric(dat[, "n"])), ]`.

Comment: Yes, almost.
The missing part is to increase date with each repetition

Comment: When you say you want the date to increase with each repetition, does that mean that `r1` stands for:
("2017-01-01 08:00:00", "a" 20); 
("2017-01-02 08:00:00", "a" 20); 
("2017-01-03 08:00:00", "a" 20); 
("2017-01-04 08:00:00", "a" 20);  
("2017-01-05 08:00:00", "a" 20)
?

Comment: thank you for your interest
this is, let say, compressed data. If n>1 that means that the same value n was reported by the same device again, during the subsequent measurements.
I.e ("2017-01-01 08:00:00", "a" 20); ("2017-01-02 09:00:00", "a" 20); ("2017-01-03 10:00:00", "a" 20);

Comment: thank you for specifying. I cannot think of anything at the moment though.

Comment: What have you tried to group your values ? Why can't you just make Data a factor and plot it for each factor? @Szelor Could you post part of your real data ? It seems like "the value didn't change during n subsequent measurements" is not correctly represented here

Comment: @Llopis for `a`, there is an entry at 08h and the next entry is 5 hours later at 14h, so the subsequent measurements all at `Value = 20` could for example be at each hour.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
dat$Date <- as.character(dat$Date)
dat$n <- as.numeric(dat$n)
dat$Value <- as.numeric(dat$Value)

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Value, color = Key, stroke = n)) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: This is certainly an efficient and simple solution, unfortunately n represents time span and must be mapped to continuous Date scale

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely what you mean, but now I adjusted the plot so that `Value` is on the y-axis, the color is chosen based on `Key`, and the dot is bigger the higher `n` is (= the number of observations for that value-key pair for the date). Is this what you wanted?

Comment: well, not exactly, but it's closer.
the problem is that "n" is not the number of occurences at given time, but the meaning is more like this "the value did't change during n subsequent measurements"
I'm wondering if I can show this on a graph without expanding (ungrouping) the data first

Comment: I'd say in a plot it's more intuitive if you do ungroup the data, which would result in a straight line in the plot for consecutive unchanged values.

Comment: You are right, the problem is the amount of data - we are talking about billions of rows here

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would ungroup the data, using dplyr chain. But as you can see, the comment of Roman is quite similar.

```
r1 <- c("2017-01-01 08:00:00","a",20,5) 
r2 <- c("2017-01-01 08:00:00","b",10,20) 
r3 <- c("2017-01-01 14:00:00","a",35,4) 
dat <- as.data.frame(rbind(r1,r2,r3),stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(dat) <- c("Date","Key","Value","n")

library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate(n = as.numeric(n)) %>%
do(.[rep(1:nrow(.), .$n),])
```